# How to create divs dynamically using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create my `divs` in a way to access my `JSON` data and display all every time I create a new `div`. I have my first `div` display information through my `JSON`. This is what I got so far:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  function function_name(data) {
    return  {data: ['nombre','telefono'],pie: 'texto'};
  }
  function _data(info) {
    return info;
  }
  (function() {
    var obj = {
      id: 'id',
      nombre: 'pepe',
      telefono: '6691296347'
    };
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var p  = document.createElement('p');
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    var _p  = document.createElement('p');
    var _span = document.createElement('span');
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    var p_ = document.createElement('p');
    var span_ = document.createElement('span');
    p_.textContent = 'ID: ';
    div.appendChild(p_);
    p_.appendChild(span_);
    span_.textContent = obj.id;
    body.appendChild(div);
    data = JSON.stringify(_data(obj));
    p.textContent = 'nombre: ';
    div.appendChild(p);
    p.appendChild(span);
    span.textContent = obj.nombre;
    _p.textContent = 'Telefono: ';
    div.appendChild(_p);
    _p.appendChild(_span);
    _span.textContent = obj.telefono;
    div.appendChild(btn);
    btn.textContent = 'button';
    btn.setAttribute("id","id");
    btn.addEventListener('click',function (e) {
      console.log(_data(obj));
    });
  })();
});
```

Comment: Insead of using an immediately invoked function, just make it actually a function you call, so you can repeatedly call it with different data sets. The just add a call for the data that has to be shown on load. Something like: `function render( data ){ .... return btn; }; ... render({data: ['nombre','telefono'],pie: 'texto'});` (advanced ps: you can clone nodes as well, no need for p, _p, p_, __p, p__, _p_, -p- etc. ;) or even better, make a createNode function)

Comment: I think the title is not appropriated for this question, please think of a better title for your question.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if the is a basic javascript way to do that ...but i use jquery to add data to every new div element

```
data = {"obj" : [{"name" : "John"}]}
```

Json that returns object

```
$.each(data.obj, function(i, message){
    var htmlMessage = "";

    htmlMessage += "<div>";
    htmlMessage += "<p>";
    htmlMessage += "<span>";
    htmlMessage += message.name;
    htmlMessage += "</div>";
    htmlMessage += "</p>";
    htmlMessage += "</span>";

    $("#body")[0].innerHtml += htmlMessage;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function for creating elements. For example:

```js
// creating elements function
function createEl(config){
    config = config || {};
    if(!config.type) throw new Error('config type required!');

    var new_el = document.createElement(config.type);
    // check text param
    if(config.text) new_el.textContent = config.text;

    // maybe check for other element attributes (id, class, etc)
    // ...

    return new_el;
}

// some code
// ...
var obj = {
    id: 'id',
    nombre: 'pepe',
    telefono: '6691296347'
};

var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var div = createEl({ type: 'div' });
var p = createEl({ type: 'p', text: 'nombre: '});
var span = createEl({ type: 'span', text: obj.nombre});
// other elements
// ...

// and then append
p.appendChild(span);    
div.appendChild(p);
body.appendChild(div);
// ...
```